# Working with a remote repository in JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am working on a project where we have to use JGit. I have a problem  when I try to work with  a remote git repository (the git that is not cloned in my local device) I receive the following exception:

No HEAD exists and no explicit starting revision was specified

If I clone the repository it works well, but repositories are quite big and I cannot clone it because of project requirements. Is there a way how to work with remote repositories? I do only simple read operations.

Comment: You can maks a *shallow* clone: https://www.perforce.com/blog/141218/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones However, not sure if JGit supports this...

Comment: What exactly are your simple read operations? Commits, or blobs, or files, or ...?

Comment: By simple read operations I mean that I am interested only in the history of the current branch. I want to only read commit messages, tag messages, etc. I am able to do it if I clone the whole repository however our repositories have around 800MB and we do not have space to clone all the repositories so I need to open repository from its current location..like http://repositorty.com/.git

Comment: For example: `Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder().setGitDir(new File("/home/juraj/Workspaces/GitPokus/eet_c3/.git")).build();` is working like a charm. But when I try to open repository that I do not have locally: `Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder().setGitDir(new File("https://kkk@codecloud.web.kk.com/scm/st_eet/kkk.git")) .build();` I get the error I mentoined in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access the history of a Git repository you need to clone it first. The clone may be bare if you are not interested in the working dir, but a clone is required.

Git allows to create a shallow clone that includes only the history up to a specified depth, however JGit still lacks support for shallow clones:
 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475615

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have to find another way how to work with the repository in my Java application.

Comment: What if I need to push an updated file to remote? Do I need to clone it first?

Answer (score 0):

JGit supports to walk the refs (i.e. tags, branches, ...) that are available remotely, see e.g. https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListRemoteRepository.java

Then you might be able to only fetch part of the repository if you provide appropriate RefSpecs.